# Using Entity Framework and check if userid exists in another table

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Using MVC3, EntityFramework 4, C#, VS 2010, I've got the following:

```
foreach (var person in _db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdated))
        {
            data.Add(new List<string>
            {
                person.UserId,
                person.FullName,
                person.Title
            }    
        }

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I'd like to add a column/field that checks another entity object to see if the person exists in another table, and then show a Y/N if they do/don't.

How would I approach this?

Comment: whats data? where are your 2 tables? you dont need for blocks if you are using linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my guess is correct you want another column in your list of string to tell you **"Y"** if person exist on that table and **"N"** if not. try doing this:

```
foreach (var person in _db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdated))
        {
            data.Add(new List<string>
            {
                person.UserId,
                person.FullName,
                person.Title,
                (_db.AnotherTable.Where(p => p.personID == person.personID).FirstOrDefault() == null? "Y": "N")
            }    
        }
```

Comment: That's it! I had to interchange the "Y" and "N" for our purposes, but it worked like a charm. It does slow down the application quite a bit, but it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help @sharcfinz. if you like the answer please dont forget to upvote. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a LINQ/Lambda outer join between this entity and the other table. Any nulls in the other table after the join indicate that the person only exists in the first table. I don't have time at the moment to write up the solution but would be happy to do that in the morning

Your Json list structure is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be correct to add foreign key to People table.
[image: forein key]
Then you can access to relations directly from the object.
Something like this

```
foreach (var person in _db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdated))
{
   data.Add(new List<string>
   {
        person.UserId,
        person.FullName,
        person.Title,
        person.SomePeople2.Any() ? "Y" : "N"
    }    
}

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But if you do not want to add a foreign key, you can do so

```
foreach (var person in _db.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastUpdated))
{
   data.Add(new List<string>
   {
        person.UserId,
        person.FullName,
        person.Title,
        (_db.SomePeople2.Any(x=>x.UserId == p.UserId) ? "Y" : "N")
    }    
}

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**UPD**
Normalized code:

```
return Json(
    _db.People.OrderByDescending(p =>
            p.LastUpdated
        ).Select(p => 
            new
            {
                ID = person.UserId,
                Name = person.FullName,
                Title = person.Title,
                InOtherTable = _db.SomePeople2.Any(x=>x.UserId == p.UserId)
            }
        ).ToArray(),
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
);
```